# Prove that $k(u, v) = \tilde{k}(\phi(u), \phi(v))$

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

Given that $\phi : \mathcal{X} → \mathcal{X}′$, prove that $k(u, v) = \tilde{k}(\phi(u), \phi(v))$.

I've seen similar proofs where if $\phi : \mathcal{X} → \mathcal{X}$, the transformation is simply in a transformation into a different kernel in the same domain (e.g. [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT15_097S12_lec13.pdf), page 18). Does the same logic apply here with the fact that $\phi$ isn't necessarily a transformation in the same dimension, but still a valid kernel? Is there a more detailed proof that can be shown?

Comment: I couldn't follow what you want to prove.